# If $\lim_{x\to 6} f(x) = -216$, find $\lim_{x \to 6} [f(x)]^{1/3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> If $\lim_{x\to 6}  f(x) = -216$, find $\lim_{x \to 6}  [f(x)]^{1/3}$.

It says to use the fractional limit law, I have no idea what this means.

The textbook example is:

> If $\lim_{ x \to 6} f(x) = -8$, find $\lim _{x\to 2}  [f(x)]^{4/3}$. 
>   Use the fractional power limit law shown below to determine your answer.

Assuming $m > 0$ and $n > 0$ are integers, $\lim_{x \to a}  [f(x)]^{n/m} = [\lim_{x \to a}  f(x)] ^ {n/m}$, provided $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x$ near $a$ if $m$ is even and $(n/m)$ are reduced to lowest terms.

I don't know what that means! My professor hardly glossed over limit laws - I can do rationalization just fine, but have no clue how to do this.

Comment: I reformatted the formulas. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

The way to apply that *limit law* is by ensuring the hypothesis is satisfied and then use the conclusion.

Restating this *law* we have:

> Given $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists then we have
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to a} (f(x))^{n/m} = \left( \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \right)^{n/m}
> $$
>   given $m$ is odd or $m$ is even and $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x \in (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$ for some small $\epsilon > 0$

To break this down, given any positive integers $m,n$ such that $n/m$ is in lowest terms (e.g. $4/8$ is not in lowest terms but $1 / 2$ is) and given that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists (for example $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist but $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{x}$ does) we have
$$
\lim_{x \to a} (f(x))^{n/m} = \left( \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \right)^{n/m}
$$
as long as $m$ is odd (e.g. $3$) or if $m$ is even then we need to have $f(x)$ be non-negative close to $x=a$. The reason for this last statement is because if we put $f(x) = x$ and $n = 1, m = 2$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we need to have that $x$ is positive close to $a$ otherwise we would be trying to approach a square root of a negative number (e.g. if $a = -2$ then we would be trying to approach $\sqrt{-2}$ which doesn't exist in $\mathbb{R}$).

I hope the above helps, if you have any questions comment below.

---

I use italics on the *law* part because this is really the definition of continuity. Since you are talking about limit laws I'm guessing you haven't talked about continuity yet, so I won't go too in depth here except to say that a function $g$ is continuous at $a$ if
$$
\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = g\left( \lim_{x \to a} x \right) = g(a)
$$
so in our case the function $g$ would be given by $g(x) = x^{n/m}$ for natural numbers $m,n$. This function is only continuous everywhere when $m$ is odd or continuous for at $a > 0$ if $m$ is even.

---

I just realized the above explanation might be much so just ignore it if it went over your head, otherwise I'm going to leave it there in case it does help you!